# TreeSHAP algorithm: how do UNWIND and EXTEND work?

Tags: algorithms, shap, explainable-ai

In the paper [Consistent Individualized Feature Attribution for Tree Ensembles](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.03888.pdf), the authors describe the well-known TreeSHAP algorithm.

It aims to calculate the SHAP values of feature $i$ for all $i$ using the following identity:
$$\phi_i(f, x) = \sum_{\{k \mid i\in D_k\}} \Bigg[\sum_{h=0}^{|D_k|-1} \frac{h!(|D_k|-h-1)!}{|D_k|!}\sum_{S\subseteq D_k\backslash \{i\}, |S| = h}\Bigg(\prod_{j\in P_k, d_j \in S}1_{\{x_{d_j} \in T_{k,j}\}}\prod_{j\in P_k, d_j \in D_k\backslash (S\cup \{i\})}R_{k, j}\Bigg)\Bigg]\cdot\Bigg(\prod_{j\in P_k, d_j = i}1_{\{x_{d_j} \in T_{k,j}\}}-\prod_{j\in P_k, d_j = i}R_{k, j}\Bigg)v_k$$
where $v_k$ is the $k$-th leaf, $P_k$ is the path from the root to the leaf $v_k$, $D_k$ is the set of unique features on $P_k$,  $d_j$ is the feature of the edge $j$ (on path $P_k$), $x_{d_j} \in T_{k,j}$ when $x$ satisifies the condition $T_{k,j}$ to go through edge $j$, and $R_{k,j}$ is the sampling weight of edge $j$.

It seems that calculations happen in the EXTEND and UNWIND procedures of the treeSHAP algorithm, but I could not understand how do these functions calculate the expression above?
For instance, why are weights $w$ calculated the way they are in EXTEND procedure?

Plus, would you know where I could find a proof of correctness of this algorithm? (for understanding purpose)